# Cassandra 3.11.3 and cqlsh not support python 3.6 and 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cqlsh

I have installed *Python 3.6 or 3.7* with *Cassandra 3.11.3*.
But it does not supporte `cqlsh`, it only supports the *Python 2.7* version.
This is the error message:

```
\apache-cassandra-3.11.3\bin\\cqlsh.py", line 146  
    except ImportError, e:  
                      ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: CQLSH only need python 2.7 version

Answer (score 1):

Cqlsh is written in Py2.7, so it'll not build on py3 wrapper env. Even if you change the exception line, it'll not compile the. For example, take this line:

```
File "/home/usr/.local/bin/cqlsh", line 212
    print '\nWarning: Specified cqlshrc location `%s` does not exist.  Using `%s` instead.\n' % (CONFIG_FILE, HISTORY_DIR)
                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Optional solutions:

- Downgrade your python version using sudo-alternatives (check versions with update-alternatives --list python)
- Correct the entire file (not viable)
- Connect throug datastax or similar driver and query.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
except a, b:
```

to

```
except a as b:
```

Add parens to prints

Answer (score 0):

Change:
       `except ImportError, e:` 
To:
 `except ImportError as ex:` 
or
`except ImportError:`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the both version, set the Python2.7 as the main one. You can check the principal version using the command `python -V`. Then change using this command `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python` (use your path python 3x and 2x). Check if it was ok using  `python -V`. Call the `$cqlsh` again.

Ps.: If necessary check the cqlsh file, if the header is correct. If it is `#!/usr/bin/python3` fix to `#!/usr/bin/python`. You can use `$find / -name cqlsh`to find the files.